# Returning multiple arrays with fetchAll in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i'm trying to retrieve multiple rows from a database. The problem i'm having is every time I use this function it replaces al the other rows I already tried to return and it only returns the last row. If anyone knows a better approach to this or knows how to actually make this work please comment.

New to posting here so apologies if this isn't correct in some way. Thanks.

My Code:

```
public function getPosts($id){
        global $pdo;

        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE f1 = ? OR f2 = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $id);
        $query->bindValue(2, $id);
        $query->execute();
        $res = $query->fetchAll();
            foreach($res as $user):
                if($user['f1'] == $id):
                    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id WHERE user_id = ?");
                    $query->bindValue(1, $user['f2']);
                    $query->execute();
                else:
                    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id WHERE user_id = ?");
                    $query->bindValue(1, $user['f1']);
                    $query->execute();
                endif;

                return $query->fetchAll(); //Trying to return arrays.
            endforeach;


}
```

Comment: My earlier comment that I deleted about stripping the while loop was bit incomplete and useless. So I posted some code instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. I don't know what f1 and f2 are so I just added them as placeholders. And I'm not using bindValue here. It's simpler to call execute using just `array($f1_id, $f2_id)`

```
public function getPosts($id){
    global $pdo;

    $f1_id = 1; //placeholder
    $f2_id = 2; //placeholder

    $posts = array();

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE f1 = ? OR f2 = ?");
    $stmt->execute(array($f1_id, $f2_id));

    //Iterate over the friend records.
    //fetch() returns next record or false on failure (No more records).
    //false terminates the while loop.
    while($user = $stmt->fetch()) {
        if($user->f1 == $f1_id) :
            $stmt_post = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id WHERE user_id = ?");
            $stmt_post->execute(array($user['f2']));
        else:
            $stmt_post = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id WHERE user_id = ?");
            $stmt_post->execute(array($user->['f1']));
        endif;

        while($post = $stmt_post->fetch()) {
            $posts[] = $post; //"$posts[] = " syntax is used to append the $post to the array.
        }
    }

    return $posts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that the results of the 'posts' query should be added to the '$res' array for each user. Then return the '$res' array rather than only the current posts for a particular user.

Untested code:

```
public function getPosts($id){
        global $pdo;

        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE f1 = ? OR f2 = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $id);
        $query->bindValue(2, $id);
        $query->execute();
        $res = $query->fetchAll();
            foreach($res as &$user): // make a reference so i can modify it
                if($user['f1'] == $id):
                    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id WHERE user_id = ?");
                    $query->bindValue(1, $user['f2']);
                    $query->execute();
                else:
                    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id WHERE user_id = ?");
                    $query->bindValue(1, $user['f1']);
                    $query->execute();
                endif;

                $user['posts'] = $query->fetchAll(); // save the current users posts.
            endforeach;

            return $res; // all users and their posts.

}
```